# What datastructure to use for creating represenation of gantt charts?

Tags: c++, data-structures, schedule

I have list of tuples with `<Task,<start_time,end_time>>`. This representation can be graphically represented as gantt chart. To support different types of queries i wish to have tree based representation over list. I can think of segment tree or range tree somewhat spatial representation. Is there any promising data structure for time-based representation of data?

Comment: "To support different types of queries" - what exactly types of queries? This will determine the choice of a data structure.
That being said, you may look at interval trees.

Comment: A gantt chart is a connected graph data structure.  That makes googling "c++ connected graph data structure" possibly fruitful.   You'll discover Boost Graph for example.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes. Data structure designed is combination of llvm::IntervalMap and Boost::DirectedGraph.